# Retrieving data from multiple tables in android sqlite database

Tags: android

I'm working on an android project in which i have a listview the listview contains datas from my existing sqlitedatabase named "Android.sqlite".the database contains two tables "users" and "post". "users" table contains two coloumns ID and NAME the data from NAME coloumn is displayed in the listview."POST" table contains 4 coloumns post_id,postname,post_desc,ID .ID is common in both tables.my need is that when i click on an item in listview ie NAME from database  table the appropriate data from post_desc coloumn must be retrieved and displayed in the next activity's textview.

database helper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.freshdatabase/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "Android.sqlite";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TB_USER = "Users";
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);    
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDB!=null){
        myDB.close();
    }
    super.close();

}
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }

}
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();        

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public List<String> getAllUsers(){
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
        if(c == null) return null;

        String name;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {            
            name = c.getString(1);            
            listUsers.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();        

    return listUsers;
}
```

}
 main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;

ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        dbHeplper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView lvUsers= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    List<String> listUsers = dbHeplper.getAllUsers();

    if(listUsers != null){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                listUsers);
        lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Make `INNER JOIN` with both tables....

Comment: @TP Tell me your Table Structure.....

Comment: i have two tables the first one table 1 contain two coloumns ID and name the second table contains post_id,post_name,post_desc,ID. ID column is same in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `SQL` Command

```
Select post.post_desc  from users INNER JOIN post ON users.ID=post.ID WHERE NAME='Listview_selected item'
```

First implement  `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
  "Click ListItem: " + listUsers.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
  .show();
}
});
```

Now, create a method in your `DatabaseHelper` for getting of `post_desc` by `Name`

```
public String getPostDesc(String Name){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c;

try {
    c = db.rawQuery("Select post.post_desc from users INNER JOIN post ON users.ID=post.ID WHERE NAME='"+Name+"'" , null);

    if(c == null) return null;

    String desc="";

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
      desc= c.getString(0);  
    }

    c.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
}

db.close();        

return desc;
}
```

Now, called this in your `ListItemClick(....)` like

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {

String Desc=dbHeplper.getPostDesc(listUsers.get(position));

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
  "Desc is: " + Desc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
  .show();
}
});
```

Comment: where i want to add this query??what code i have to write in onitemclick method??

Comment: @Thusharaprasad Just Get Name onitemclick() and pass this into my query and execute.You'll result as per selected Name.

Comment: can you plse show me the example?? where i will write this query?

Comment: thanku for ur answer but its showing no such table post.but i have the table post in my database..

Comment: @Thusharaprasad Try to uninstall your app and install again a fresh APK built.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65684/discussion-between-thushara-prasad-and-m-d).